# Stopping Music in SpriteKit when leaving a GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, avfoundation

I have implemented background music in my game using AVFoundation. However, when leaving the GameScene the music continues playing. I know that in viewControllers you can use viewWillDisappear but I can't find anything similar for GameScenes.

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "electroDrive", ofType: "wav")

//.......//

//.......//

    do {

        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))

    }
    catch {
        // process error

    }

    audioPlayer.play()


//Code to go to other scene
if viewController != nil {
        self.viewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "push", sender: viewController)
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for when you go to the next scene?

Comment: Yes, give me one sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stop the AVAudioPlayer before segueing to the next Scene**

Insert this before your segue code

```
audioPlayer.pause()
```

Comment: Yeah. The moment I saw your comment I figured it out. Thanks man!